# I don't see someone or I didn't see someone?

Tags: grammar

When I was working alone and someone came to me and asked: “Do you know where Amy is?” Should I respond to my colleague “I don’t see her” or “I didn’t see her?”

I’m confused about in which situation that I should say “I don’t see someone” or “I didn’t see someone”.

Comment: Neither: the normal answer would be "I don't know!" or simply "No!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Frank comes in and asks "Do you know where Amy is?"

The normal response, if you are not somehow in charge of keeping track of people and you have not recently seen Amy, would be:

> I haven't seen her.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see someone is the correct answer

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your post to explain *why* that is the correct answer. Note that we're not like other sites; an answer on EL&U is expected to be authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct. For further guidance, see How to Answer and take the EL&U Tour. Your answer would have been fine as a Comment, but, under the site rules, you are not able to leave comments until you have have earned sufficient reputation on the site.